# Using a simulation in R to test coverage probability of a confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a homework question which asks me to test the coverage probability of a confidence interval (found as part of a previous question) using a simulation in R.

My code is attempting to generate 1000 random samples (with replacement) from the sample data I have, effectively treating my original sample as my new population. The random samples are the same size as my population. I then want to find the 95% confidence interval for each random sample and see how many contain the 'true mean' (given in the problem statement) vs. the 'population mean' (the mean of my original sample).

```
set.seed(1987)

iq <- rnorm(1000,91.08065,14.40393)

pop_mean <- mean(iq) #the mean of my sample is now considered the population mean
true_mean <- 100 #the true mean is 100, specified in question

sampSEs <- numeric() #create an empty vector to put the sample SEs in
sampMeans <- numeric() #create an empty vector to put the sample means in

get_conf_interval <- function(sample_measurements) {
  iqSE_samp <- 15/sqrt(length(iq)) #find the SE using an sd of 15
  iqMean_samp <- mean(sample_measurements) #take the mean of each sample
  upper <- iqMean_samp + 1.96*iqSE_samp #find the upper bound for a 95% CI
  lower <- iqMean_samp - 1.96*iqSE_samp #find the lower bound for a 95% CI
  list(lower=lower, upper=upper)
}

interval_contains_true_mean <- function(interval) { #check if the interval contains the true mean
  true_mean >= interval$lower && true_mean <= interval$upper
}
interval_contains_population_mean <- function(interval) { #check if the interval contains the population mean
  pop_mean >= interval$lower && pop_mean <= interval$upper
}

samples <- replicate(1000, sample(iq, size = 124, replace = T)) #take 1000 samples with replacement from my iq data

for(i in 1:1000) { #for each sample taken
  sampMeans[i] <- mean(samples[i]) #put the mean of it in the vector created previously
  sampSEs[i] <- 15/sqrt(length(iq)) #put the SE in a vector... these are all the same bc not finding the sample sd
}

intervals <- apply(samples, FUN=get_conf_interval, MARGIN=2) #call the function to find the confidence intervals

sampMeans #just check if worked
#sampSEs #ditto

percent_intervals_with_true_mean <- mean(sapply(intervals, FUN=interval_contains_true_mean)) * 100
cat("% Intervals Containing True Mean: ", percent_intervals_with_true_mean, "%\n")

percent_intervals_with_pop_mean <- mean(sapply(intervals, FUN=interval_contains_population_mean)) * 100
cat("% Intervals Containing Population Mean: ", percent_intervals_with_pop_mean, "%")
```

This code reports that 0% of the confidence intervals for my samples contain the true mean. This is not correct; I have looked at the sample means and several of them ARE the true mean.

Comment: What is your `iq`? Provide a definition (e.g. `iq <- rnorm(1000,100,15)`) to make this reproducible. When I run your code on such an `iq` I *don't* get your `0%` answer. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, the IQ data I am using in my assignment is a separate csv file. I have added a statement to the above code that generates IQ values with the mean and sd of the values in my file since I don't think I can attach it. Hopefully this will be ok for testing? Using this code, I get that 55.4% of the intervals contain my population mean, but still 0% of the intervals contain the true mean. With this new data, none of my random samples have a mean of exactly 100, but some are very close (100.12716 for example) so I still don't think this can be correct.

Comment: But now, since your mean of `iq` is around `91.08065`, why do you think that the "true mean" is 100? Your edit has caused the question to make less sense.

Comment: This is part of a larger assignment, and this sample (my original csv) is selected from an area of high lead exposure. The true mean in this case is the mean IQ of the US population, which I do not expect to be the mean of this sample. I don't expect 100 to be in the confidence intervals of most of the samples drawn from this pool, but I expect it to be in a nonzero percentage of them. I'm sorry if the structure/terminology is confusing, I just wanted to trim it down for posting as this is about 1/20th of the real thing.

Comment: I wouldn't expect 100 to be in any of 1000 confidence intervals when drawing samples of size 124 from that population. The sample means will have expected value of around 91 and a standard deviation of around 15/sqrt(124) which is around 1.3. Note that 9/1.3 is nearly 7, so your "true mean" is 6 to7 standard deviations above the expected sample mean.

Answer (score 0):

1.- i have two solution the first solution is put comma in 'mean(samples[,i])' and

'set.seed(1987)

sigma_M=14.40393

mu_M=91.08065

m=10

iq <- rnorm(m,mu_M,sigma_M)

pop_mean <- mean(iq) #the mean of my sample is now considered the population mean

samples <- replicate(m, sample(iq, size = 4, replace = T)) #take m samples with replacement from my iq data

sampSEs <- numeric() #create an empty vector to put the sample SEs in

sampMeans <- numeric() #create an empty vector to put the sample means in

for(i in 1:m) { #for each sample taken

sampMeans[i] <- mean(samples[,i]) #put the mean of it in the vector created previously

sampSEs[i] <- 15/sqrt(length(iq)) #put the SE in a vector... these are all the same bc not finding the sample sd
}

get_conf_interval <- function(sample_measurements) {

iqSE_samp <- 15/sqrt(length(iq)) #find the SE using an sd of 15

iqMean_samp <- mean(sample_measurements) #take the mean of each sample

upper <- iqMean_samp + 1.96*iqSE_samp #find the upper bound for a 95% CI

lower <- iqMean_samp - 1.96*iqSE_samp #find the lower bound for a 95% CI

list(lower=lower, upper=upper)
}

interval_contains_population_mean <- function(interval) { #check if the interval contains the population mean

pop_mean >= interval$lower && pop_mean <= interval$upper
}

intervals <- apply(samples, FUN=get_conf_interval, MARGIN=2) #call the function to find the confidence intervals

sampMeans #just check if worked

## sampSEs #ditto

percent_intervals_with_pop_mean <- mean(sapply(intervals, FUN=interval_contains_population_mean)) * 100

cat("% Intervals Containing Population Mean: ", percent_intervals_with_pop_mean, "%")'

2.- the second solution is change the code but i did only  'pop_mean' population mean
(and calculate standard desviation)

'set.seed(1987)

sigma_M=14.40393

mu_M=91.08065

m=10

iq <- rnorm(m,mu_M,sigma_M)

pop_mean <- mean(iq) #the mean of my sample is now considered the population mean

samples <- replicate(m, sample(iq, size = 4, replace = T)) #take m samples with replacement from my iq data

sampMeans=apply(samples, 2, mean)

iqSE_samp <- 15/sqrt(length(iq)) #find the SE using an sd of 15

iqMean_samp <- sampMeans #take the mean of each sample

upper <- iqMean_samp + 1.96*iqSE_samp #find the upper bound for a 95% CI

lower <- iqMean_samp - 1.96*iqSE_samp #find the lower bound for a 95% CI

intervals=cbind(lower, upper)

percent_intervals_with_pop_mean=mean(apply(intervals, 1, findInterval, x = pop_mean) == 1)*100

cat("% Intervals Containing Population Mean: ", percent_intervals_with_pop_mean, "%")'

and the final is 80 porcent for me